# linq group by twice

Tags: c#, linq

We have a survey. and I have a model as follows:

```
Survey
    City 
    Satisfaction
    Id
```

Satisfaction is an enum as follows:

```
Satisfaction: 
    VerySatisfied, 
    Satisfied
    Undecided, 
    NotSatisfied
```

I am interested in grouping by city and then I want to group by VerySatisfied and satisfied.

```
 var result= _db.Surveys.AsNoTracking()
    .GroupBy(x => x.City)
    .Select(group => new { 
        City = group.Key.Code, 
        CityName = group.Key.Name, 
        Count = group.Count() 
     })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

I can do group by City, but I need to find the Satisfaction ratio within the city.

ie: New York: %90 percent.

How can i group by twice to get the result above?

Comment: How should we know what `Satisfaction ratio` means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var result= _db.Surveys.AsNoTracking()
               .GroupBy(x => x.City)
               .Select(group => new 
                      {
                            City = group.Key.Code, 
                            CityName = group.Key.Name, 
                            Count = group.Count(),
                            SatisfactionRatio = (group.Count(y => y.Satisfaction == Satisfaction.VerySatisfied || y.Satisfaction == Satisfaction.Satisfied) * 100) / group.Count()
                      })
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Comment: Even better: `group.Count(y => y.Satisfaction == Satisfaction.VerySatisfied ||  y.Satisfaction == Satisfaction.Satisfied)`

Comment: You need to do : `.GroupBy(x => new { x.City, x.Name })` to get CityName in result.

Comment: @RahulSingh I didn't change that part of the code, this part was written by OP. And I think that in `City` included Code and Name.